# MEF container auto-update using a directory-catalog

Tags: directory, containers, mef, catalog, auto-update

This is possible if we manually create a `FileSystemWatcher` and watch the 'parts' directory (here some dlls inside the folder) and track any changes, then we reflect the changes into a container which allows for recomposition.

Does `MEF` support auto-updating when the `Container` is using a `DirectoryCatalog` and it automatically for us ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the `Refresh` method of the DirectoryCatalog for it to update with new contents.  This will trigger recomposition in any containers hooked up to the catalog.  You can create a FileSystemWatcher and call the Refresh method when anything changes.

Comment: I did it as you say and everything is OK with new parts but I cannot replace existing parts. It seems MEF put a lock on my dlls. How to dynamically replace parts (each part in a single dll in plugins folder) ? thanks

Comment: @Xaqron It's .NET that has a lock on your DLLs.  You can't unload assemblies from an AppDomain, and while they are loaded there will normally be a lock.  You can enable shadow copying for the AppDomain to let you delete the DLLs.  They would still be loaded but the DirectoryCatalog would see they were gone when you called Refresh and remove them from the catalog.